# Easy tool to decompose sprite image?

Tags: css, image, sprite, photoshop

I have a lot of sprite images that contain dozens of icons.  Is there an easy way to unravel the sprites into separate image files either automatically or feeding it coordinates, widths and heights?

Comment: Good question, I always get this problem, sprites take ages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the slice tool in Photoshop:

1. Use the `slice select tool` (note the **select** part of that, see screenshot).
2. Right-click anywhere on the canvas and select `Divide Slice...` from the drop down menu.
3. Enter in the height/width or sprite multiple.
4. Once finished, go to `save for web and devices...`
5. When you save, this will export all the individual cutouts to the file format of your choosing in a separate folder.

If they are of uneven size (not on a grid) you can also select them individually with the vanilla 'slice select' tool.  If you have a lot of similar grids, save everything as a photoshop action and batch process them.

[image: slice **select** tool]

Comment: The idea was to decompose a sprite image into individual images.  I has nothing to do with CSS sprites.

Comment: this is very time consuming, the answer from BYS2 is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 15):

This program is pretty good at decomposing sprites into individual frames

https://github.com/ForkandBeard/Alferd-Spritesheet-Unpacker

it supports all standard bitmap formats, .png, .bmp, .gif, .tiff and does everything pretty much automatically.

Comment: when i drag the sprite onto the application then click export selected, it freezes...

Comment: @abadaba, oh really? it seems to work well for me :S.. do you have a copy of your sprite that I can download from the internet? I've tried it on some of my own and it seems to work perfectly

Comment: Ok...this was just awesome. Worked perfectly. I was not expecting it to do ALL the work for me. Thanks a ton!

Comment: this program works great! for the people for which it freezes when you export it, according to the FAQ you have to unselect the "export to folder" checkbox, that did the trick for me :)

Comment: good to know my suggestion is still being looked at after all this time :P

Comment: @BYS2 No doubt this one should be the correct answer. That program is amazing!! Thanks!!

Comment: Also, laughed on the FAQ: -"Do you know how to spell Alfred?" -"Yes".

Comment: It has to be run as an administrator (on Windows 8 at least)

Comment: Link not working for me

Answer (score 6):

I encountered a similar problem after losing the source images for a sprite and built this relatively simple tool: https://github.com/fmovlex/desprite

Hope this helps.

Comment: note this only works when you have an CSS file containing the width/height and background-position of the individual images, when you only have a sprite image this option won't help you

Answer (score 6):

This one worked nicely for me to extract images from jquery ui sprites http://renderhjs.net/shoebox/

Answer (score 5):

give this as try as it will split it into individual rows: http://imagesplitter.net

Comment: But this assumes every row is the same height, images may take up difference space.

Answer (score 0):

There is an android application that will dynamically split a sprite map:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fourqueue.android.texture

Answer (score -2):

**Creation of png**:

I use spritepad to create the png image, just drag and drop your images to create the sprite: http://spritepad.wearekiss.com/ (but as I assume you dont want this step).

**CSS**:

After this I import the image to spritecow and get the css for every image (double click every image to get its height-width and coordinates): **http://www.spritecow.com/**

You could use spritepad only but I prefer to use it only for the creation of the sprite. For css, spritecow seems easier to me. Anyway its up to you.